# I want to call a contract method using my safe wallet address

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe, smart-contract-wallets, multisignature

I made a safe wallet in my panel safe wallet which is 2/3 signers. I want to use it in my access control for an admin role and use it for calling a transfer method with it only. The problem is when I want to call a method in one of my contract. I couldn't figure it out. can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are asking how to call a contract via safe wallet.

**For that, head over to safe wallet, and you'll see this new transaction button, clicking on that, you'll see this interface.**

[image]

**Click on transaction builder and Paste the contract address**

[image]

**Scroll down and you'll see the methods to call, select whatever function you wanna call, pass the arguments, and click on add transaction.**

[image]

After that, you can create multiple transactions and execute all of them at once. You can also execute a single transaction

Comment: Your response made a big difference. Appreciate it! Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Special note, the contract needs to be verified to pull the ABI automatically.

If it doesn't have this, then you can copy and paste in the ABI from your favourite tool.