# How can I use Gnosis Safe multisig to execute state functions in a contract it owns?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have a simple ERC20 contract from OpenZeppelin with owner only mint function.

I want to transfer ownership to a multisig, such that any owner only state functions need to meet the n/x threshold of the multisig.

How can I do this?

I have transferred ownership to the gnosis safe proxy. However, the gnosis-safe interface doesn't allow me to post owner only transactions to the contract.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have already answered this question here - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/156666/i-want-to-call-a-contract-method-using-my-safe-wallet-address/156668#156668